# How can I customize tabs in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, customization

I am trying to create customized, togglable tabs in wordpress, but I am stuck. I would like to change the title part of the tabs to images. Something like that, but in wordpress:

http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/ttpxoxob/1/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">
      <img src="http://www.downloadsbyvita.com/images/video.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use bootstrap or [inbuilt jquery ui](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress). Or [Tabs Shorcode plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabs-shortcode/)

Comment: Thanks I will try your suggestions!